# Остановка Windows службы

Tags: c#

Возникла следующая проблема с работой windows службы.
У меня имеется windows служба, которая выполняет сложный статистический анализ с пересылкой данных между несколькими серверами. Анализ выполняется по таймеру (`system.timers.timer`) в методе `OnStart`. Время выполнения одного анализа довольно большое (может достигать 20 минут). Проблема заключается в остановке данной службы. Если попытаться остановить ее в тот, момент, когда запущен анализ, то она намертво повисает и запустить или удалить ее из системы становится очень проблематично. Если же остановить ее в момент простоя, то она успешно завершает свою работу.

В службе есть метод `OnStop`, но я слабо понимаю как можно остановить выполняющийся анализ с помощью данного метода. Посоветуйте какое-нибудь решение данной проблемы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможные костыли:

1. делать фоновому потоку Thread.Abort()
2. поставить фоновому потоку IsBackground = true

В обоих случаях вам придется отказаться от стандартного таймера в пользу своего потока. В этом потоке вам придется крутить бесконечный цикл с Thread.Sleep() между вызовами.

Эти костыли плохи тем, что могут оставить фоновой процесс в неправильном состоянии. К примеру, он может записать в БД половину информации, а остальную не успеть или что-нибудь в этом роде. Но если природа процесса такова, что его можно прервать в любой момент - этим способом можно пользоваться.

---

Теперь про правильный способ. Причина проблемы - следующая.

Главный метод вашей службы выглядит, скорее всего, примерно так:

```
static void Main() {
  ServiceBase.Run(new FooService());
}
```

Когда `FooService` получает сигнал останова - он отмечается как завершенный, и `ServiceBase.Run` завершает работу. Это приводит к завершению работы метода Main - но остается еще фоновой поток.

Что видит диспетчер сервисов? Процесс продолжает работать - поэтому новый запускать нельзя. Но и сигналы управления старый процесс не принимает...

Для того, чтобы избежать этой ситуации, надо выполнить два действия.

1. Корректно прервать выполнение задачи анализа при получении сигнала Stop.
2. Дождаться окончания обработки фоновой задачи перед выходом из OnStop.

Первый пункт нужен. чтобы служба могла завершиться быстрее чем за 20 минут, второй - чтобы она не выглядела зависшей.

---

Для того, чтобы корректно прервать выполнение задачи анализа - надо такое прерывание предусмотреть в самом алгоритме анализа. К примеру, завести какой-нибудь булев флаг и периодически проверять его.

Но есть способ лучше, и называется он - [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx).
Ну а для того чтобы дождаться окончания обработки, удобно создать новый поток и ждать его.

Вот пример подобного сервиса:

```
class FooService {
  private readonly CancellationTokenSource ctsStop = new CancellationTokenSource();
  private Thread thread;

  protected override OnStart(string[] args) {
    thread = new Thread(ThreadProc) { IsBachground = false };
    thread.Start(ctsStop.Token);
  }

  protected override void OnStop() {
    ctsStop.Cancel(); // Отменяем выполнение задачи, если она запущена
    thread.Join();
  }

  private void ThreadProc(object obj) {
    var token = (CancellationToken)obj;
    do {
      RunTask(token);
    } while (!token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(...));
  }

  private void RunTask(CancellationToken stopToken) {
    // тут ваша аналитика
  }
}
```

В ходе выполнения задачи надо периодически выполнять проверку `stopToken.IsCancellationRequested`, и если она вернула true - то надо по-быстрому закругляться.

Если вам надо подождать - то вместо `Thread.Sleep` лучше сделать `stopToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne`.

Ну и плюс можно подписаться на событие отмены, сделав `stopToken.Register` (но во избежание утечек памяти все подобные вызовы надо делать в using-блоке).

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете остановить выполняющийся код просто так, код должен *сотрудничать*. Например, вы можете использовать булев флаг со смыслом «нужно прекратить вычисления», и проверять его в вычисляющем коде. (Не забудьте защитить переменную `lock`'ом при многопоточном доступе.)

Или можно использовать `CancellationToken`, он специально для этого придуман.