# Как в сервисе на С# перед остановкой службы дождаться окончания выполнения запущенной задачи?

Tags: c#, windows-service, служба

Здравствуйте.
Как в сервисе на С# перед остановкой  службы дождаться окончания выполнения запущенной задачи? При запуске программы как обычного сервера проходит 
await unfinishedTask. 
В сервисе await в OnStop игнорируется и сервис сразу же останавливается.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неверное понимание конструкции `await`. Эта конструкция планирует продолжение текущего метода после окончания задачи - но она не продлевает время выполнения метода. Когда вы используете `await` в методе `OnStop` - метод заканчивается сразу после оператора `await`, окончание метода планируется для асинхронного выполнения.

**В данном случае вам надо использовать синхронное ожидание - метод `Wait()` или свойство `Result`.**

PS Недавно приводил общую схему для службы с потоком: [Остановка Windows службы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534924/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-windows-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%8B/534943#534943) К задаче она тоже подойдет.

Comment: Cпасибо сработало. А нет ли ограничений на продолжительность обработки OnStop?

Comment: @ВладимирМадорин ограничение есть, пять секунд вроде. Потом остановка службы будет считаться неудачной. Но это не помешает службе остановиться потом.

Comment: @ВладимирМадорин а, нет, вру - 30 секунд ограничение: [Service Control Handler Function](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534924/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-windows-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%8B/534943#534943)